# How to select rows from a CSV file based on different column values?

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv

I have a CSV file with values like the following:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
1,0,0,0,0,BTS,Active
4,5,3,1,1,LocalMode,Offlne
1,2,5,6,3,PermFault,Offline
1,2,6,6,2,BSC,Active
7,8,2,3,2,NE,Offline
1,7,6,5,2,BSC,Active
```

I want to fetch the values rows from this CSV file in such a way that the following sample conditions are met:

1)  if (col7="Active" )
    then 
        sum of col1 values from all the rows

2) if (col6 == somevalue && column5 != somevalues)
then
      sum of col1 values from all the rows.

I am able to fetch the rows from CSV file based on one column values which meets my first condition with the following awk command:

```
awk -F, '$7 == "Active" { print }' test.csv
```

How can i use multiple conditions in this awk command which checks multiple column values as mentioned in above sample condition 2 where i need to check present of some specific text in col6 and at the same time i need to ignore some keywords from column5. Is there a better and easier way of doing this instead of awk?

Answer (score 2):

From [The AWK Programming Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020107981X):

> The simplest awk program is a sequence of pattern-action statements:
>   `pattern { action }`
>   `pattern { action }`
>   ...

So, you can try following:

```
awk -F, '
         $7 == "Active" { x += $1; };
         $6 == "value6" && $5 != value5 { y += $1; };
         END { print x, y; }
        ' file
```